# Why does removing validation samples from Keras model improve test accuracy so much

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I'm doing a programming assignment for Andrew Ng's Deep Learning course on Convolutional Models that involves training and evaluating a model using Keras.  What I've observed after a little playing with various knobs is something curious:   The *test* accuracy of the model greatly improves (from 50 percentile to 90 percentile) by setting the `validation_fraction` parameter on the `Model.fit` operation to 0.   This is surprising to me; I would have thought that eliminating the validation samples would lead to over-fitting of the model, which would, in turn, reduce accuracy on the test set.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: You just have more training data, that's just it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is more training data, but the increase is pretty negligible since dI was setting the validation fraction to 0.1, so that would increase the training data by 11.111...%   However, thinking about it some more, I realized that removing the validation step doesn't have any effect on the model, hence no impact on test accuracy.  I *think* that I must have changed some other parameter, too, though I don't remember which.

Answer (score 0):

As Matias says, it means there is more training data to work with.

However, I'd also make sure that the test accuracy is actually increasing from 50 to 90% consistently. Run it over a couple times to make sure. There is a possibility that, because there is very little validation samples, that the model got lucky. That's why it is important to have a lot of validation data - to make sure the model isn't just getting lucky, and that there's actually a method to the madness.

I go over some of the "norms" when it comes to training and testing data in my [book](https://www.energize.ai/stockprediction/) about stock prediction (another great way in my opinion to learn about Deep Learning). Feel free to check it out and learn more, as it's great for beginners.

Good Luck!